# How can I access income variable in calculateGradeBonus() method of TournamentIncome.java?

Tags: java

application consist of the
following files.

1. Player.java (abstract base class)
2. Tax.java (interface)
3. PlayerIncome.java (extends player implements Tax) + income variable
4. GradeBonus.java (interface)
5. TournamentIncome.java (extends player implements Tax)
6. PlayerTest.java

Task:
Create a new instance of class TournamentIncome and store the details in the three parameters
name, grade and rate. Now, create a method calculateGradeBonus() to calculate the bonus of
each player based on his grade. Create a method displayDetails() to display the details about each
player. Here, calculate the income of the player using his income and the bonus amount he will
be given as per his grade.

```
public class PlayerIncome extends Player implements Tax {

double income;
double tax;

public PlayerIncome(String name, double income) {
    super(name);
    this.income = income;
}

@Override
public void calculateTax() {
    tax = income * (TAX_PERCENT / 100);
}

@Override
void displayDetails() {
    System.out.println("Player Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Income: " + income);
    System.out.println("Tax: " + tax);
}
```

}

Income is an instance variable of PlayerIncome Class.

```
public class TournamentIncome extends Player implements GradeBonus {

String grade;
int rate;

public TournamentIncome(String name, String grade, int rate) {
    super(name);
    this.grade = grade;
    this.rate = rate;
}

@Override
public void calculateGradeBonus() {
    
}

@Override
void displayDetails() {
     
    
}
```

I want to use that income variable in TournamentIncome Class for calculating Bonus

```
public abstract class Player {
String name;

public Player(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

abstract void displayDetails();
```

}

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Pleae put in your post the code of mentioned classes. Please point out where lays the problem and how did you try to resolve it.

Comment: @fascynacja Now you can check

Comment: @PratikSingh I see that you are new to stack overflow. Please take it as a friendly advice and read the: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: the Player class code will be also needed to help you find solution.

Comment: from the classes and description I see that you have to: create a method calculateGradeBonus() to calculate the bonus of each player based on his grade. (this will happen in the TournamentIncome  class) so why you need to get the income variable in this method?

Comment: Because if Grade is A and rate is 10% so to calculate the 10% amount of his income i need to access the income variable.

Comment: Also in displayDetails() i need income + bonus to calculate final income

Comment: Please add also your PlayerTest. I am struggling to understand the concept of all this classes together. For instance why Tournament extends Player. It will be usefull to understand what are the real instances in the "game". H the objects are being initialized and how the TournamentIncome is initiliaized. How they relate to each other in a test scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it, hope it helps:

Something I noticed:

1. PlayerIncome doesn`t belong to Player, so don`t extend Player, also TournamentIncome.
2. we can use return value of a method for further usage, like you don`t have to keep a tax field(I think you have to initialize tax field before you access it, if you want to initialize tax field, then do it in constructor of PlayerIncome class)

```
public abstract class Player {
    String name;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    abstract void displayDetails();
}
public class PlayerIncome implements Tax {

    Player player;
    double income;

    public PlayerIncome(Player player, double income) {
        this.player = player;
        this.income = income;
    }

    @Override
    public double calculateTax() {
        return income * (TAX_PERCENT / 100);
    }

    @Override
    void displayDetails() {
        System.out.println("Player Name: " + player.name);
        System.out.println("Income: " + income);
        System.out.println("Tax: " + calculateTax());
    }
}
public class TournamentIncome implements GradeBonus {

    PlayerIncome playerIncome;
    String grade;
    int rate;

    public TournamentIncome(PlayerIncome playerIncome, String grade, int rate) {
        this.playerIncome = playerIncome;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    @Override
    public int calculateGradeBonus() {
        if (this.grade == "A" && rate == 10) {
            return (int)this.playerIncome.income * 10 / 100;
        }
        return (int)this.playerIncome.income * 5 / 100;;
    }

    @Override
    void displayDetails() {
        System.out.println("Player Name: " + playerIncome.player.name);
        System.out.println("FinalIncome: " + calculateGradeBonus());
        System.out.println("Tax: " + playerIncome.calculateTax());
        System.out.println("Grade: " + grade);
        System.out.println("rate: " + rate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you cleared my doubt.